# How to select a subset of records using Doctrine when working with 2 entities in a ManyToOne Association?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to find out a way to properly select a subset of records using ORM such as Doctrine in my case.

```
$rep = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Entity\ServiceLineItem');
$serviceItems = $rep->findBy(...);
```

In my case I want to select all instances of ServiceLineItem that have a `$serviceType` of "Testing".

In my code I have created the following two entities:

```
/** @Entity */
class ServiceLineItem
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /**@ManyToOne(targetEntity="ServiceType") */
    private $serviceType;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    private $description;
}

/** @Entity */
class ServiceType
{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(length=255)*/
    private $serviceType;
}
```

My database looks like this:

```
serviceLineItem(id INT, serviceType_id INT, description VARCHAR);
serviceType(id INT, serviceType VARCHAR);
```

I am looking for a PHP ORM Doctrine equivalent of

```
select * 
from ServiceLineItem 
join ServiceType on ServiceLineItem.ServiceType_id = ServiceType.id
where ServiceType.name = "Testing";
```

Currently I am using

```
$serviceItems = $rep->findBy(array(
     //"Testing" has an index of 1 in the database table
    'serviceType' => '1'
));
```

I am looking for a way to avoid using underlying database indices and use higher-level constructs, such as actual values (i.e. "Testing").    How can I do that in Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

### Single Table Inheritance

Maybe you're looking for [Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). In this case you have different model classes for a single table 'discriminated' by a specified column.

See:

- [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)
- [Single Table Inheritance Pattern (Martin Fowler)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

### Current approach

In this case you must use a [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) query. Use `$em->createQuery(<query>);` or the built-in QueryBuilder:

1. Use a custom repository by extending your model's annotations:

   ```
   /**
    * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\ServiceLineItemRepository")
    */
   ```
2. Create the repository with your find method:

   ```
   class ServiceLineItemRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
   {
       public function findByServiceType($serviceType)
       {
           $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('item');

           if ($serviceType instanceof ServiceType) {
               $queryBuilder->where('item.serviceType = :type')
                   ->setParameter('type', $serviceType);
           } else {
               $queryBuilder->innerJoin('item.serviceType', 'type')
                   ->where('type.serviceType = :type')
                   ->setParameter('type', $serviceType);
           }

           return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
       }
   }
   ```

---

**!! Everything untested !!**

Comment: well thanks!  so there is no "easy" way ... ...   I saw creating custom DQL pieces elsewhere, but I figured there was some way an ORM can do a simple JOIN for you, without specifying custom DQL.  I am half-tempted to remove the Association and create a single table (as in pull in my "serviceType" category into "ServiceLineItem" itself and remove foreign keys, associations, et)   Or just use two-repository approach - pull The ServiceType, get its index, feed that index into ServiceLineItem.   I am looking for the easier way .. .. if one exist. (aka without a DQL.  But I'll take what I can get..

Comment: AFAIK there is no easier way. I would recommend using custom DQL. This way you have to inject only one single repository instance to your service or controller class. It is the job of your repository to fetch the requested results with their dependencies. With the two-repository approach you would have to add another layer to your application to strictly follow the single responsibility principle. Anyway I don't see a reason to not use DQL at all.